# WordPress: Set 'Featured image' as first ACF-gallery when saving post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I found this function [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/display-1-gallery-picture-on-archive-page/).
I'm using ACF pro.

Update: I added variable according to comment below, this got rid of the error, however the function is still not working.

**functions.php:**

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_featured_image_from_gallery' );

function set_featured_image_from_gallery() {
  $post = get_post(); //Edit according to comment below      
  $has_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

  if ( !$has_thumbnail ) {

    $images = get_field('gallery', false, false);
    $image_id = $images[0];

    if ( $image_id ) {
      set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $image_id );
    }
  }
}
```

**Error message when saving post (pressing "Update"-button):**

Notice: Undefined variable: post in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pf-blank/wp/wp-content/themes/PF-Blank-theme/functions.php on line 600

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pf-blank/wp/wp-content/themes/PF-Blank-theme/functions.php on line 600

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pf-blank/wp/wp-content/themes/PF-Blank-theme/functions.php:600) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pf-blank/wp/wp-admin/post.php on line 197

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pf-blank/wp/wp-content/themes/PF-Blank-theme/functions.php:600) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pf-blank/wp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174

Comment: firstly you need to get your posts data in $post varriable then and then you can use $post->ID , which you have passed in function, so using get_posts data get all the post data in to $post varriable and then try

Comment: adding a `$post = get_posts();` doesn't work, tried with a foreach-loop round the `$has_thumbnail`, didn't work either. Could I get a code example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass parameters in **get_posts** function by giving arguments.

**Try below code:**

```
function set_featured_image_from_gallery() {

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC');
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
      $has_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

      if ( !$has_thumbnail ) {

        $images = get_field('gallery', false, false);
        $image_id = $images[0];

        if ( $image_id ) {
          set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $image_id );
        }
      }
      endforeach; 
    }

    add_action( 'save_post', 'set_featured_image_from_gallery' );
```

Comment: For this to work: `$postlist = get_posts( $args );` == `$postslist = get_posts( $args );` & `if ( $has_thumbnail ) {` == `if ( !$has_thumbnail ) {`

Comment: @Carl Papworth sorry didn't get it you elaborate more ? my solution is not worked for you ?

Comment: The function works except there are some typos: `$postlist` variable-name isn't same, and `$has_thumbnail` should be `!$has_thumbnail` so that it doesn't change a previously set thumbnail. This is just for copy/paste-purpose. Cheers.